# How to use `indirect_call` in WebAssembly?

Tags: webassembly

There is no example of use of `indirect_call` available online. Based on semantics documentation, I tried

```
(call_indirect 
    (i32.const 0)
    (i32.const 0)
    )
```

Numbers are random, but instead of giving run-time error which I would have expected. I am getting parsing error.

What is the correct syntax for `call_indirect`?

Answer (score 7):

The correct syntax for `call_indirect` appears to be

```
(call_indirect $fsig
   (i32.const 0)
)
```

Where `$fsig` is the expected function signature as defined in the `type` section and the argument is the address of the function (or rather its index in the `table`).

Take for example the following C code example calling a function pointer:

```
typedef void(*fp)();

void dispatch(fp x) {
  x();
}
```

It [compiles](https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/?state=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22showGutter%22%3Atrue%2C%22showConsole%22%3Atrue%2C%22showOptions%22%3Atrue%2C%22autoCompile%22%3Atrue%2C%22showLLVM%22%3Afalse%2C%22darkMode%22%3Atrue%2C%22fastMath%22%3Afalse%2C%22noInline%22%3Afalse%2C%22noRTTI%22%3Afalse%2C%22noExceptions%22%3Afalse%2C%22cleanWast%22%3Afalse%2C%22wasmBaseline%22%3Afalse%2C%22dialect%22%3A%22C99%22%2C%22optimizationLevel%22%3A%22s%22%7D%2C%22source%22%3A%22typedef%20void(*fp)()%3B%5Cr%5Cn%5Cr%5Cnvoid%20dispatch(fp%20x)%20%7B%5Cr%5Cn%20%20x()%3B%5Cr%5Cn%7D%5Cr%5Cn%22%7D) to

```
(module
  (type $FUNCSIG$v (func))
  (table 0 anyfunc)
  (memory $0 1)
  (export "memory" (memory $0))
  (export "dispatch" (func $dispatch))
  (func $dispatch (param $0 i32)
    (call_indirect $FUNCSIG$v
      (get_local $0)
    )
  )
)
```

Here is a more complete example where we actually call a function `test` that returns a value:

```
(module
  (type $FUNCSIG$i (func (result i32)))
  (table 1 anyfunc)
  (elem (i32.const 0) $test)
  (memory $0 1)

  (func $test (type $FUNCSIG$i) (result i32)
    (i32.const 42)
  )

  (func $main (result i32)
    (call_indirect $FUNCSIG$i
      (i32.const 0)
    )
  )

)
```

Comment: That's correct. To add to your answer (specifically, question says there are no examples online), there are examples in the spec repository's test suite: https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/blob/master/test/core/call_indirect.wast

Comment: @JFBastien Thanks for pointing to examples. I think webAsm guys should give this link in documentation somewhere or the semantics page. They are really helpful but it might not occur to someone to look into the test files.

Comment: @abhishek the semantics are completely separate from the text format and stand on their own. That's because the text format is just a convenience, it's one of many possible ways to represent the WebAssembly binary format. The spec is where things are formally specified, but it's still a work in progress. When done it'll specify both semantics formally, without reference to the text format, and will separately specify the text format.

Answer (score 3):

An excerpt from the documentation:

> Tables are basically resizable arrays of references that can be
> accessed by index from WebAssembly code. To see why tables are needed,
> we need to first observe that the call instruction takes a static
> function index and thus can only ever call one function — but what if
> the callee is a runtime value?
>
> - In JavaScript we see this all the time: functions are first-class values.
> - In C/C++, we see this with function pointers.
> - In C++, we see this with virtual functions.
>
> WebAssembly needed a type of call instruction to achieve this, so we
> gave it call_indirect, which takes a dynamic function operand. The
> problem is that the only types we have to give operands in WebAssembly
> are (currently) i32/i64/f32/f64.
>
> WebAssembly could add an anyfunc type ("any" because the type could
> hold functions of any signature), but unfortunately this anyfunc type
> couldn’t be stored in linear memory for security reasons. Linear
> memory exposes the raw contents of stored values as bytes and this
> would allow wasm content to arbitrarily observe and corrupt raw
> function addresses, which is something that cannot be allowed on the
> web.
>
> The solution was to store function references in a table and pass
> around table indices instead, which are just i32 values.
> call_indirect’s operand can therefore be an i32 index value.

So, to sum it up, `call_indirect` needs the signature for validation, and takes  an `i32` value as an argument that points to the required function in the respective table. As with other WASM instructions, the argument can be either be popped from the stack, or retrieved from nested instructions. Thus we can have:

```
call_indirect (type 123)      ;; Type as an index in the table,
                              ;; argument on the stack from previous instructions.
```

or

```
call_indirect $funcSignature  ;; The same, but using a type name instead of index.
```

or

```
(call_indirect $funcSignature ;; The argument is provided by the nested instructions.
      (get_local $0)
)
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Understanding_the_text_format#webassembly_tables